# If and else script to detect the name of an object and then prevent the rest of my script from running

Tags: python

I have an object named "Square" and it is selected in the scene. I would need to detect if the name of the object is like "Square" and if so, do nothing. Else, continue with the rest of the script.

```
if  bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Square*")
else:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import bpy
import re

a = bpy.context.selected_objects

if len(a) == 1:
    obj = a[0]
    if re.search("Cube.*", obj.name) != None:
        print("do nothing")
    else:
        print("rest of script")


        # your code here but with same(!) indentation

# if you paste code here, the if-statement won't work
```

How does an if-statement work in python?

```
if a == b:  # condition
    print("a equals b")
    # all statements with this indentation will be executed only if a equals b
# all statements with this indentation will always be executed
```

How to use a function in python?

```
def myFunction():

    print("my thousands lines of code")

if a == b:
    print("i do nothing here")
else:
    myFunction()
```

complete code:

```
import bpy
import re


def myFunction():

    print("my thousands lines of code")

    
    a = bpy.context.selected_objects
    
    if len(a) == 1:
        obj = a[0]
        if re.search("Cube.*", obj.name) != None:
            print("do nothing")
            
        else:
            print("rest of script")
            
            myFunction()
```

Comment: The script currently ignores the "Cube" and runs rest of the script. I am missing something. Ta

Comment: Can you show a video or provide your blend file? I have no idea what you did ;) Did you select your cube when the script run? else the script won't work...the script itself works. I tested it. And of course you should rename "Cube" to "Square" if you need this...

Comment: https://youtu.be/XWRkEwEwEXs

Comment: you have to indent all your code to the same place as i did with "print ("rest of script")" else the code will be executed.

Comment: I have over a thousand lines of script following, is there a way of doing the first script.. and then reverting to the first line?

Comment: what about just using a function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126879/discussion-between-michael-teiniker-and-chris).